# iAd -- cannot click banner

Tags: iphone, templates, xib, iad, universal

I am creating a universal-app template.

This template will need to support optional iAds,  and optionally all orientations.

I coded up a solution only to find a bizarre bug.   in certain situations I was unable to click on the banner

I then recoded another revision,  tidied everything, and gutted out most of the code to reveal a minimal test case failure.

https://github.com/p-i-/iAdUniversalTemplate/commit/2c829d268a9452e1a054802e7ccb9cde5de17853

In this new code,  only 3 views: window, uberview (the view controller's view),  and the ad-banner

So, the banner displays properly once it has been served, autorotation works fine...
I have logged the frame and bounds for each, and everything is as it should be.

But it is not responding to tap (well, click because I am in the simulator)

What could possibly be wrong?  I'm starting to suspect that in cutting the XIB out of the project and implementing the window and view controller from code, I have missed something out or wired something up back to front.

Juicy code chunks:

***AppDelegate.m***

```
- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *) launchOptions 
{
    NSLog(@"--> ___PROJECTNAME___AppDelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...");

    // FIXED: now entry in info.plist hides SB BEFORE launch
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: (SHOW_SB ? NO : YES)];

    CGRect appFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;

    // windowRect must start at 0, 0
    // if (SHOW_SB == YES), appFrame will be '{{0, 20}, {320, 460}}'
    CGRect windowRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, appFrame.size.width, appFrame.size.height);

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: windowRect] autorelease];

    self.viewController = [ [ [ ___PROJECTNAME___ViewController alloc ] init ] autorelease ];

    [self.window setRootViewController: viewController];

    // triggers loadView
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

***iAdVC.m***

```
- (void) loadView 
{       
    self.uberView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame] autorelease];
    self.uberView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.uberView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.uberView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    //UIWindow * w = self.view.window;
    //w.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [self setView: uberView];

    showingBanner = NO;
    adBannerView = nil;
    if (IADS_ENABLED)
    {
        NSString * P = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        NSString * L = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;

        self.adBannerView = [[[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];

        self.adBannerView.delegate = self;
        self.adBannerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
        self.adBannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects: P, L, nil];
        self.adBannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( self.interfaceOrientation ) ? P : L ;

        [uberView addSubview: adBannerView];
    }

    UIWindow * w = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

    w.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.uberView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.adBannerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    w.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.uberView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.adBannerView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    w.opaque = YES;
    self.uberView.opaque = YES;
    self.adBannerView.opaque = YES;
}

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

#pragma mark Autorotate

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation 
{   
    return YES;
}

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) newOrientation 
                                 duration: (NSTimeInterval) duration
{
    bool isLandscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(newOrientation);
    self.adBannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = isLandscape ? ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait ;
}


#pragma mark Banner

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd: (ADBannerView *) banner 
{   
    if (! showingBanner)
    {
        showingBanner = YES;
        // ... (optionally animate in)
    }
}


// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

- (void) bannerView: (ADBannerView *) banner 
didFailToReceiveAdWithError: (NSError *) error
{
    NSLog(@"FAIL");

    if (showingBanner)
    {
        showingBanner = NO;
        // ... (optionally animate out)
    }
}

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

-(BOOL) bannerViewActionShouldBegin: (ADBannerView *) banner 
               willLeaveApplication: (BOOL) willLeave
{
    return YES; // doesnt get hit
}

// = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the banner to the middle of the window (feed the proper CGRect into initWithFrame), just to be sure it isn't obscured by some other invisible view you may be adding elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a bitch of a bug to blat

I ended up having to use one of my 2 ITS helpline incidents,  and lost a full working week on it.

Setting the uberView's backgroundColor property to ANYTHING non-nil fixes the problem.

This is one of the things that gets done by XIB magic

There is a tool called nib2objc  that converts XIB into code.   this would have been the next step if I had to debug it myself,  to actually see what is contained in Apple's default XIB,  and see what I'm failing to implement manually.

But this is a BUG in UIKit.  Apple's ITS rep told me to file it does such, which I have done.

Comment: Thank you!  I would have never guessed it had anything to do with the background color.  Just spent several hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: I never thought that setting the background color of the banner to clear would stop it from working, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but using [UIColor clearColor] for the superview's background did not help. (This is on iOS 4.3.3)

All the superviews need to have an *opaque* color set.

Answer (score 0):

I do confirm that adding

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

in *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* function works perfectly.