# XIB-less iOS project template refuses to receive touch events

Tags: ios, xib, manual, touch-event

As the title says... I'm creating a template purely from code, ie without using XIBs.

So I create a window and a view controller,  and the view controller in turn creates a view

( I am going to provide the answer below, just putting this up so is to save someone from banging their head from week on it.   I'm creating a new question because the first question was poorly formed -- the solution had nothing to do with iAd framework, I should have debugged further and figured this out before posting. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a UIKit bug.   Full answer at [iAd -- cannot click banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475404/iad-cannot-click-banner/5534826#5534826)

The solution is to set the background colour of the view to anything!  eg [UIColor redColor]